# Convert python to kivy language

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, kivy

I am new to python and more to kivy, with this it turns out that they helped me to create this code (below), it turns out that after my code seems to work well, many told me that for good practices I did not write I will create graphic environments with python that existed for that .kv, with this clearer it turns out that I have not been able to achieve how I do it, I hope you could help me to transcribe it I thank you from the bottom of my heart thank you, below the code, I just want to transcribe what I have thanks.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.clock import Clock
import cv2

class CvCamera(App):
    def build(self):  # Construcción de interfaz de usuario, etc
        self._cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        layout2 = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal', size_hint=(1.0, 0.1))
        self.img1 = Image(size_hint=(1.0, 0.7))
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        layout.add_widget(self.img1)
        layout.add_widget(layout2)

        while not self._cap.isOpened():
            pass

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 30.0)
        return layout

    def update(self, dt):
        ret, img = self._cap.read()
        img = cv2.flip(img, 0)
        texture1 = Texture.create(size=(img.shape[1], img.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
        texture1.blit_buffer(img.tostring(), colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        self.img1.texture = texture1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CvCamera().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the equivalent using `kv` language:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.clock import Clock
import cv2

kv = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Image:
        id: img1
        size_hint: 1.0, 0.7
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint: 1.0, 0.1
'''

class CvCamera(App):
    def build(self):  # Construcción de interfaz de usuario, etc
        self._cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        layout = Builder.load_string(kv)

        while not self._cap.isOpened():
            pass

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 30.0)
        return layout

    def update(self, dt):
        ret, img = self._cap.read()
        img = cv2.flip(img, 0)
        texture1 = Texture.create(size=(img.shape[1], img.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
        texture1.blit_buffer(img.tostring(), colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        self.root.ids.img1.texture = texture1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CvCamera().run()
```

Note that, in general, the arguments in `()` of the `Widgets` become entries below and indented from the `Widget` name.